# Will I earn bonuses by accomplishing a mission remaining unseen?

Tags: warframe

If I go quiet, and I kill everyone without giving them the chance to see me, will I get a bonus of something, or it's the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the new rescue missions, there is no bonus for remaining undetected during a mission. In the new rescue missions, you are awarded a point for each of the following objectives:

> Killing all of the 'Wardens' protecting the hostage
>
> Rescuing the hostage before the Wardens can set off the Execution command (Similar to an alarm, triggering a 60 second countdown before the hostage is killed and the mission fails)
>
> Escaping with the hostage

Depending on the specific mission you played, you will be awarded a Specter Blueprint depending on your total points earned during the mission. Aside from this specific case, no, Stealth does not award any bonus to a mission.